# Quartz scheduling a job on every Application Run in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

I have a spring quartz application.

It is scheduling a cron every time I run the application. I want it not to set the cron again if job already exist.

Code for scheduling

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void assignJobs() throws IOException, SchedulerException {
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(CollectTransactionDataJob.class)
                .withIdentity(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), CollectTransactionDataJob.GROUP)
                .withDescription(CollectTransactionDataJob.DESCRIPTION)
                .storeDurably()
                .build();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .forJob(jobDetail)
                .withIdentity(jobDetail.getKey().getName(), CollectTransactionDataJob.TRIGGER_GROUP)
                .withDescription(CollectTransactionDataJob.TRIGGER_DESCRIPTION)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(10, 30))
                .build();

        Scheduler scheduler = quartzConfig.schedulerFactoryBean().getScheduler();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
    }
```

Expected behaviour:

```
If CRON time is 10:30
Current time is 10:00
Between 10:00 and 10:30 the apllication in RUN 2 times
Then at 10:30, the CRON should RUN 1 time.
```

Observed behaviour

```
At 10:30, the CRON RUNs 2 times.
```

Quartz properties

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

Comment: use the 3 param scheduleJob with the 3rd param being `replace`?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I find only ONE PARAM (Trigger) and TWO PARAM(JobDetail, Trigger) methods. NO 3 param method found.

Comment: what version are you using? see https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.3/index.html

Comment: @ScaryWombat Working now. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet is working fine.

Thanks @ScaryWombat for suggestion

3 param method of `scheduleJob` had to be used with REPLACE boolean as `true`.

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void assignJobs() throws IOException, SchedulerException {
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(CollectTransactionDataJob.class)
                .withIdentity(CollectTransactionDataJob.NAME, CollectTransactionDataJob.GROUP)
                .withDescription(CollectTransactionDataJob.DESCRIPTION)
                .storeDurably()
                .build();

        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .forJob(jobDetail)
                .withIdentity(jobDetail.getKey().getName(), CollectTransactionDataJob.TRIGGER_GROUP)
                .withDescription(CollectTransactionDataJob.TRIGGER_DESCRIPTION)
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(12, 41))
                .build();
        Set<Trigger> setTrigger = new HashSet<>();
        setTrigger.add(trigger);

        Scheduler scheduler = quartzConfig.schedulerFactoryBean().getScheduler();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, setTrigger, true); // enable REPLACE here
    }
```